# Flutter web unable to load assets from packages

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm testing flutter web for one of my web app.

I've noticed that if I use a package that has some preloaded assets to be displayed, the web app will say that it is unable to load assets.

I tried with these packages:

```
 1. flutter_country_picker
 2. cool_alert
```

The error that I get is:

```
Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/packages/cool_alert/assets/flare/success_check.flr" (404)
```

I've read that the problems depends on the fact that flutter web uses another way to get the assets.

Is there a way to solve address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at those packages, and it's actually the packages themselves:

**pubspec.yaml**

```
assets:
  - assets/flare/
```

Packages should be calling in asset's differently to avoid this error:

```
assets:
  - packages/cool_alert/assets/flare/
```

I would recommend either raising an issue or create a PR with the package authors.